# Python-Print 3rd digit of a number

Tags: python

```
N=int(input("Enter the number: "))
N=N-((N//10)*10)
print(N)
```

This only valid for 3 digits i want a code for any no with any no of digits

Comment: How about `str(N)[2]` (with some necessary error handling, for example when `N` has less than three digits)?

Comment: i am a newbie so my teacher wants a logic with number and operators only

Comment: The point of getting a task like that is to attempt to solve it yourself so that you learn along the way; start by trying to find out why the example code works as it does. You don't learn by getting the right answer, you learn by finding out how to get there by yourself.

Comment: i dont know the question itself is very unclear

Comment: `str(N)[2]` is the right answer. If you need to implement it using a specific language feature or technique, let us know. To be honest, it is a terrible assignment.

Comment: yeah i know thanks for the help

Comment: i was just trying to get the advice

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
N = int(input("Enter the number: "))
if N > 99:
    while N > 999:
        N = N // 10
    N = N % 10
    print(N)
else:
    print('Need 3+ digits number')
```